# Xamarin freehand draw on a Google Map

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin

I need a way for the user to free hand draw on a Google Map.  I have the Map Interface working, but there doesn't seem to be any real mouse events other than click.  I have seen some javascript examples where they hook the mousedown and mousemove events, but I don't see these events exposed in Xamarin.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: you would need to layer a transparent element on top of the map to capture the drawing events

Comment: @Jason I need to be able to capture the longitude and latitude as I draw so I can draw the line again later.

Comment: then you'll need to translate the x,y points to geo points - it doesn't change the need to have a drawable canvas on top of your map.  There may be other ways to approach this, but this is the most obvious (to me) way

Comment: @JimWilcox Did you ever resolve this?  I'm facing the same need and wondering which direction you went with this.

Comment: @MarkErickson I gave up to be honest.  There are examples out there that use the native Android interface, but Xamarin doesn't expose the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup events so it seemed more trouble than it was worth.  If you figure out a way to do it, I would appreciate if you let me know.